# Was Benaiah afraid to kill Joab in the sanctuary in 1 Kings 2:

Tags: 1-kings, niv, solomon

Solomon instructs Benaiah to kill Joab regardless that he was in the sanctuary holding onto the horns of the Altar.Benaiah seems to hesitate and instead negotiates with him to come out of the sanctuary

After failing to convince Joab he returns to king Solomon to report back before he returns and  eventually  he executes him

1 Kings 2:28-31 NIV

28 When the news reached Joab, who had conspired with Adonijah though not with Absalom, he fled to the tent of the Lord and took hold of the horns of the altar. 29 King Solomon was told that Joab had fled to the tent of the Lord and was beside the altar. Then Solomon ordered Benaiah son of Jehoiada, “Go, strike him down!”

30 So Benaiah entered the tent of the Lord and said to Joab, “The king says, ‘Come out!’”

But he answered, “No, I will die here.”

Benaiah reported to the king, “This is how Joab answered me.”

31 Then the king commanded Benaiah, “Do as he says. Strike him down and bury him, and so clear me and my whole family of the guilt of the innocent blood that Joab shed.

Was Benaiah afraid to strike him while he was in the sanctuary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Benaiah killed a lion.
2 Samuel 23

> 20 Benaiah son of Jehoiada, a valiant fighter from Kabzeel, performed great exploits. He struck down Moab’s two mightiest warriors. He also went down into a pit on a snowy day and killed a **lion**. 21And he struck down a huge Egyptian. Although the Egyptian had a spear in his hand, Benaiah went against him with a club. He snatched the spear from the Egyptian’s hand and killed him with his own spear. 22Such were the exploits of Benaiah son of Jehoiada; he too was as famous as the three mighty warriors. 23He was held in greater honor than any of the Thirty, but he was not included among the Three. And David put him in charge of his bodyguard.

Why did he hesitate to kill Joab?

Out of respect for the sacred altar, he preferred to kill Joab outside of the tent.

> 1 Kings 2:30 So Benaiah entered the tent of the Lord and said to Joab, “The king says, ‘Come out!’ ”
>
> But he answered, “No, I will die here.”

Benaiah then double-checked with King Solomon and killed Joab on the spot.

Was Benaiah afraid to kill Joab in the sanctuary in 1 Kings 2?

No, it wasn't fear but respect for the sacred altar.

For a job well done, the king promoted him.

> 1 Kings 2:34 So Benaiah son of Jehoiada went up and struck down Joab and killed him, and he was buried at his home out in the country. 35The king put **Benaiah son of Jehoiada over the army in Joab’s position** and replaced Abiathar with Zadok the priest.

Benaiah was a fearless might man.